# Tikz externalize resulting in legends with wrong style

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external, externalize

I have an issue that has already been discussed in some form for example [here](https://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/7948/markierung-in-pgfplotlegende-fehlerhaft-ubernommen) and [here](https://www.texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/9476/labels-an-pgfplots) but I have not been able to resolve it with the hints/solutions given there.

Please consider the following example:

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,filecontents,tikzscale}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[mode=list and make,prefix=tikz/]

\begin{filecontents*}{fig1.tikz}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[domain=0:2]
            \addplot[red,mark=o] {sin(x)};
            \label{pgf:plot1}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{fig2.tikz}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[domain=0:2, legend to name=mylegend]
            \addplot[blue,mark=square] {cos(x)};
            \addlegendentry{cos}
            \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle={pgf:plot1}}\addlegendentry{sin}%
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \tikzsetnextfilename{mylegend}%
        \ref{mylegend}\\
        \tikzsetnextfilename{fig1}%
        \includegraphics{fig1.tikz}
        \tikzsetnextfilename{fig2}%
        \includegraphics{fig2.tikz}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

To be sure that I always recompile with sufficient prior `pdflatex` runs, I used the following dummy script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function c () {
        echo "========== PDFLATEX ========="
        pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "main".tex
        echo "========== END PDFLATEX ========"
}

rm tikz/*
rm main.aux
rm main.figlist
rm main.makefile
rm fig1*
rm fig2*
rm main-figure*


mkdir tikz

c
c

make -f main.makefile -j4 # to compile fig1, fig2

c
c

make -f main.makefile -j4 # to compile the legend (and for some reasons also again fig2)

c
```

which results for me in the results given here
[image]

where the legend for `sin` does not have the right line and marker style.

---

**EDIT:**

I guess `\tikzset{external/optimize=false}` is possible but very inconveient workaround.